# Замена данных в колонке DataFrame по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется `df` с колонками `col1` и `col2`. Задача состоит в том, что в случае наличия в `col1` определенного значения, например `'0&&&&'`, выполнялось доопределение данных из `col2` с помощью регулярки `pattern = r'\d{2}U[A-Z]{2}'` и записывалось в `col1`. Запись должна выполняться только при нахождении одного совпадения.
Мое решение:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['0&&&&','0&&&&','1&&&&'], 
                   'col_2': ['Протон 13UBN','out 00UBN 10UKA', '10UBB'], 
                   index=1, 2, 3})
```

```py
def define_units(row):
    pattern = r'\d{2}U[A-Z]{2}'
    if row['col1'] == '0&&&&':
        result = re.findall(pattern, row['col2'])
        if len(result) == 1:
            return result[0]
        else: 
            return row['col1']
    else:
        return row['col1']

df['col1'] = df.apply(define_units, axis=1)
```

Было:

```
Index  col1    col2
1     0&&&&   Протон 13UBN
2     0&&&&  out 00UBN 10UKA
3     0&&&&  10UBB
```

Стало:

```
Index  col1    col2
1     13UBN   Протон 13UBN
2     0&&&&  out 00UBN 10UKA
3     0&&&&  10UBB
```

Возникшие сложности:

1) Хотел бы значение условия `if row['unit'] == '0&&&&'`, а именно, `(0&&&&)`, передавать в функцию параметрически. Не очень понимаю, как это можно сделать.

2) Хотел бы записывать в df только доопределенные данные. А при данном подходе приходиться еще и перезаписывать данные не удовлетворяющие условию.

Comment: Вы можете привести больше примеров, включая те, где заменять строки не надо и привести пример того что должно получиться на выходе?

Comment: Подправил в описании.
Под условия подошел только 1-й элемент фрейма.
2-й не подходит по условию: if len(result) == 1: (нужно только единственное совпадение с шаблоном).
3-й не подходит по условию: if row['col1'] == '0&&&&':.
При отсутствии совпадения, перезаписываю текущие данные, что бы не потерять: else: return row['col1'].
В идеале, нужна функция с параметрами: row, pattern, значение для условия (0&&&&), 
col1 и col2. Можно использовать индекс. Результат от этого меняться не должен, просто в моем случае, данные с индексами 2 и 3 - перезаписываются. Хотел бы этого избежать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['0&&&&','0&&&&','1&&&&'],
    ...:                    'col_2': ['Протон 13UBN','out 00UBN 10UKA', '10UBB']},
    ...:                    index=[1, 2, 3])

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   col_1            col_2
1  0&&&&     Протон 13UBN
2  0&&&&  out 00UBN 10UKA
3  1&&&&            10UBB
```

Вспомогательный Series:

```
In [31]: tmp = df['col_2'].str.findall(r'\d{2}U[A-Z]{2}')

In [32]: tmp
Out[32]:
1           [13UBN]
2    [00UBN, 10UKA]
3           [10UBB]
Name: col_2, dtype: object
```

Замена:

```
In [33]: df.loc[(df['col_1'] == '0&&&&') & tmp.str.len() == 1, 'col_1'] = tmp.str[0]
```

Результат:

```
In [34]: df
Out[34]:
   col_1            col_2
1  13UBN     Протон 13UBN
2  0&&&&  out 00UBN 10UKA
3  1&&&&            10UBB
```

PS `df.apply(function, axis=1)` - один из самых медленных способов работы с Pandas DataFrame

PPS все функции поиска и замены в Pandas работают с единственным RegEx шаблоном - передать сразу несколько шаблонов не получится. Вместо этого *иногда* можно использовать более сложные шаблоны.

Comment: Спасибо, MaxU!
Красиво